# Was Sura Rum verse 1-5 revealed after Romans were victorious?

Tags: hadith, tafseer, quran-translation

This [hadith](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:3192) from tirmidhi says -

> Abu Sa'eed narrated: "On the Day of Badr, the Romans had a victory
> over the Persians. So the believers were pleased with that, then the
> following was revealed: 'Alif Lam Mim. The Romans have been defeated,
> up to His saying: 'the believers will rejoice - with the help of
> Allah... (30:1-5)'" He said: "So the believers were happy with the
> victory of the Romans over the Persians."

From the wording, it sounds like it was revealed on the day Romans were victorious.

Comment: I've a long answer to your question and I plan to write it down soon inchallah, because it's a good one. I thought of putting the main points here for now because I might post it too late. So I claim that: 1. It was revealed when the Persians were victorious as Battle of Karbala said. 2. but regarding the hadith: 1. An ayah can be revealed more than one time in throughout the Sīrah.  2. Some people interpret the word نزلت (revealed) as "being read" in this Hadith. 3. Many people question the credibility of this hadith. I will clarify more with resources in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

The verse is saying "will rejoice" so the verse is predicting the future. so  No, it was revealed when the Persians were victorious, but the Quran predicted the victory of the Romans after this defeat. In fact, the believers were happy because the prediction of the Quran.

[Reference](https://en.wikishia.net/view/Sura_al-Rum)

Comment: Your answer doesn't address the wording of the hadith.